# Very newbie troubleshooting. Basic p5.js index.html setup on Atom, not generating anything on browser?

Tags: processing, atom-editor, p5.js

literally just got into the world of coding, so if my question seems absolutely insane, I do apologise.

Anywho, was following some tutorials (Daniel Shiffman's https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZ4D3wDRaec)  how to setup a basic p5.js file on Atom, and generate a green window to test if the code is working. Really basic setup, nothing should've went wrong.

For some reason the text editor wouldn't read my code while I was typing; so then I clicked on the index.html file from the root folder.

Instead of having to show a green window, nothing actually happened. I don't know if this is a software issue, seems like nobody has encountered such a basic problem.

Nothing seems to be wrong here. And it opened a white window when it should've been green

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show your file content as code rather than as images, as it makes things easier for ops. Some good practices here can help you: [mcve]. Could you show your index.html file also?

Comment: Take a look at the developer tools of Atom (or the browser you're using). Are there any errors shown in the console or the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

You might have missed a couple of steps in the video:

1. You can simply (manually) **double click index.html** from the **yayme** folder on your Desktop. This should open your default browser with the page. This works for simple sketches but once you start loading assets (images/sounds/data from other sites, etc.) it's best to use a local web server
2. You can use any http server as Daniel Shiffman's video mentions or the [atom-live-server](https://atom.io/packages/atom-live-server) package (notice the **install** button on that page which will open Atom for you). Once that's installed you can access it via **Atom > Packages>  atom-live-server**

Comment: Hi, I did these exactly the steps, however it just wouldn't do anything, which is why I was quite confused

Comment: Must be something else then. Can you please post your index.html file and check the JavaScript Console in your browser for errors (and post them off any).